# How to set multiple site_dir in shiny-server.conf

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

Currently my shiny-server.conf looks like this:

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as ubuntu shiny;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838;

  # Define a location at the base URL
  location / {

    # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

    # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

    # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
    # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
    directory_index on;
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can set multiple directories in this line?

`site_dir /srv/shiny-server`

e.g.  by adding  `/my_favorite/app_path1/` on top of it.

Comment: Not an answer, but you can put your app in `/my_favorite/app_path1/` and then just create a symbolic link pointing to it in `/srv/shiny-server`.

Comment: @nicola can you give example. For example I want `/my_favorite/app_path1/` to be like `/srv/shiny-server` under `app_path1` there will be many applications.  I tried. `sudo ln -s /my_favorite/app_path1/ /srv/shiny-server/`. But my apps in `app_path1`, is not recognized by the browser.

Comment: You create a link for each app (not just one for the entire directory). Say you have `app1` inside your custom path. With `ln -s /my_favorite/app_path1/app1/ /srv/shiny-server/app1` you create the link and now the app should be reachable. FWIW, this is how I handle this issue.

Comment: @nicola Did you mean `ln -s /my_favorite/app_path1/app1/ /srv/shiny-server` ?

Comment: No. I intended as I wrote. Inside `/srv/shiny-server/` you create an `app1` link that points to your app. Then, you can reach your app inserting `servernaname:3838/app1` in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

AS I understand it, the question is: "how to set multiple directories in shiny-server"?

This is my shiny-server.conf:

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838;

  # Define a location at the base URL
  location / {

    # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

    # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

    # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
    # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
    directory_index on;
  }
}
```

Taking the above into account, you can create as many directories you want under `/srv/shiny-server`, e.g.:

```
+---/srv/shiny-server
|   +---Test
|       +---server.R
|       +---ui.R
|   +---Foo
|       +---server.R
|       +---ui.R
```

Then you connect to each application with:
`http://<ip address>:3838/Test` or `http://<ip address>:3838/Foo` etc.

Of course, if there is no desire to have physical directories under `/srv/shiny-server` it is possible to symlink them: for example, the directory `sample-apps` where the standard examples of shiny are stored, is symlinked from `/opt/shiny-server/samples/sample-apps`.

It is also possible to have per-users directories, but this seems to be out of the question's scope.